# Calculating the limits for a double integral for exponential density functions

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to calculate a double integral of two variables a and b, and I get the correct answer if I integrate over a first and b second but not the other way around. I am wondering where I am making the mistake.

assume $A \sim exp (\mu)$ such that $f_A(a) = \mu e^{-a\mu}$ and $B \sim exp (\lambda)$ such that $f_B(b) = \lambda e^{-b\lambda}$. I am skipping some details that are not relevant here but let's say there's another variable $T = \min(A,B)$ and I want to calculate $P(B \leq t \leq A)$.

Here's my attempt to solve the question. If we integrate over A first, the limits for A are [B, $\infty$], then the limits for B become [0,t] which makes the integration:

$$ \begin{align}
& \int _{0}^{t} \lambda e^{-b\lambda} \int_{b}^{\infty} \mu e^{-a\mu} \,da\,db \\
& \int _{0}^{t} \lambda e^{-b\lambda}  - e^{-a\mu} |_{b}^{\infty} \,db \\
& \int _{0}^{t} \lambda e^{-b (\mu + \lambda)} \,db \\ 
&=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}(1 - e^{-(\lambda + \mu) t})
\end{align}$$

which is the correct answer. Now I wanted to calculate this integral the other way around; i.e. first integrating over B and then A. Then I thought the limits of B would be [0, A] and the limits of A would be [t, $\infty$] which made my calculation:

$$\begin{align}
& \int _{t}^{\infty} \mu e^{-a\mu} \int_{0}^{a} \lambda e^{-b\lambda} \,db\,da \\
& \int _{t}^{\infty} \mu e^{-a\mu}  - e^{-b\lambda} |_{0}^{a} \,da \\
& \int _{t}^{\infty} \mu e^{-a\mu} (1 - e^{-a\lambda}) \,da \\ 
& \int _{t}^{\infty} \mu e^{-a\mu}  - \int _{0}^{t} \mu e^{-a(\lambda+\mu)} \,da \\
&=-e^{-a\mu}|_{t}^{\infty} + \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} e^{-(\lambda + \mu) a} |_{t}^{\infty}\\
&= e^{-t\mu} - \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} e^{-(\lambda + \mu)t}
\end{align} $$

which is not equal to the solution. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: It is important to know whether $A,B$ are independent or not.

Comment: If they are independent  then I would have thought $P(B \leq t \leq A) = (1-e^{-\lambda t})e^{-\mu t}$ which is not what you have.